# What is the difference between ifeq( $(foo), ) and ifndef foo

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

According to [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html) , it seems that both of these condition will be evaluated to the same results, so what is the difference between them?

```
ifeq ($(foo),)
    execute somethings
endif
```

and

```
ifndef foo
   execute somethings
endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ifdef/ifndef do not expand the variable.

Example which shows different behavior:

```
bar =
foo = $(bar)

ifndef foo
$(info yes)
else
$(info no)
endif

ifeq ($(foo),)
$(info yes)
else
$(info no)
endif
```

Output:

```
no
yes
```

The first one sees the value "$(bar)" and fails. The second one expands the variables inside foo so it becomes "" and it passes.

Comment: Quote from the manual: "Note that ifdef only tests whether a variable has a value. It does not expand the variable to see if that value is nonempty."

Comment: Note that `ifndef foo …` is a lot like `ifeq (,$(value foo)) …`. Neither will complain when `--warn-undefined-variables` is in effect.